# What the heck is this invisible question and and answer post?

Tags: support, bug

Sorry to cross-post this between here [and Meta SuperUser](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/13898/what-the-heck-is-this-invisible-question-and-and-answer-post), but this is very strange and seems to be something larger than what SuperUser mods usually handle.

I honestly don’t know [how I got to this oddly empty thread on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/1510536) to even link to it, but what the heck is this about?

> [image: The thread that doesn’t exist.]

Comment: Just flag it, they are using Unicode alternative spaces. It's a dupe, which I'll search for in an hour or two.

Comment: Just a quick note on the user: they're a known cross-site troll that has been suspended multiple times on different sites.